# I have an issue with a while read line bash script with sed command to delete lines, and following lines

Tags: bash, sed, while-loop

I have a bash script with which I'd like to read a list of lines from SedTest.names and delete that line and the following line in the file SedTest.fasta. The script looks like

```
while read line; do
 sed "/${line}/{N;d}" SedTest.fasta 
done < "SedTest.names"
```

SedTest.fasta looks like

```
>seq1
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>seq2
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
>seq3
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
>seq4
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
>seq5
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
>seq6
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
>seq7
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
>seq8
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
>seq9
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
>seq10
JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
```

And SedTest.names looks like

```
>seq3
>seq5
>seq6
```

When I run the script and direct output to test.out, test.out looks like

```
>seq1
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>seq2
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
>seq4
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
>seq5
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
>seq6
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
>seq7
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
>seq8
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
>seq9
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
>seq10
JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ

>seq1
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>seq2
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
>seq3
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
>seq4
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
>seq6
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
>seq7
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
>seq8
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
>seq9
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
>seq10
JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ

>seq1
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>seq2
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
>seq3
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
>seq4
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
>seq5
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
>seq7
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
>seq8
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
>seq9
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
>seq10                     
JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
```

It has removed the line and following line as asked, but has edited the data in SedTest.fasta for each of the 3 lines from SedTest.names separately. I need one set of out data modified by having all of the 3 lines, and their following lines, removed, making an outfile 14 lines in size.
I feel very close with this approach but I'm too thick to know why it's not working. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using inline flag in sed and that is not saving the file in place. Use your loop like this:

```
while read -r line; do
   sed -i.bak "/$line/{N;d;}" SedTest.fasta
done < SedTest.names
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava. I had to modify it a little to get it to work. It did not like the single quotes '' which seemed to stop it from seeing the required line in SedTest.fasta:                                                                                      sed: can't read />seq3/{N;d;}: No such file or directory
sed: can't read />seq5/{N;d;}: No such file or directory
sed: can't read />seq6/{N;d;}: No such file or directory
Final script looks like (-r seems to not change things)   'while read line; do
 sed -i "/$line/{N;d;}" SedTest.fasta
done < SedTest.names'  Thanks again.

Comment: Just a note for any other interested parties this script changes the infile and a re-direct to an outfile is not permitted as far as I can see (which isn't too far!). I'd suggest making a copy of your infile if you need the original version later.

Comment: Actually `-i.bak` is safer approach as it edits the file inline while saving original in a file with `.bak` extension (see updated answer)

Comment: What I found with the -i.bak option was that it was saving a back-up of the one-before-last version of the loop. So the original was still changed. Do you get the same?

Comment: Yes I also get the same. You can also avoid `-i` and redirect the output only once outside loop like this: `done < SedTest.names > output`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that each `sed` command processes the whole file for each line in the `names` file. I prefer `awk` as alternative because it can use associative arrays to save values from different files and process them only once, like:

```
awk '
  FNR == NR { names[$1] = 1; next }
  { if ($1 in names) { getline; next } }
  { print }
' SedTest.names SedTest.fasta
```

In the `FNR == NR` block save the names into an array, and for the second one compares if it exists, then `getline` reads next line and skips it. The rest are printed as normal

It yields:

```
>seq1
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>seq2
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
>seq4
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
>seq7
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
>seq8
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
>seq9
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
>seq10
JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
```

Comment: Many thanks Birei.While the sed option now works it does not seem to allow a stdout redirect, so the infile is changed permanently. I can see how this awk option may be a more elegant option, assuming you can direct the output to an outfile.

Comment: @DanielJ: The OS does that job, appending `> SedOutfile.txt` after the `fasta` files.